# Oracle Data Densification Filling in Gaps

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Attempting to fill in the gaps for reporting purposes on a table that is only updated when the values change on the table.

[image]

**Code:**

```
WITH 
week_list AS --List of weeks
 (
  SELECT (  (trunc(to_date('06152012','mmddyyyy'), 'IW')+7) - (LEVEL * 7) )+6 as week 
      from dual
      connect by level <= 7
  order by ( (trunc(to_date('06152012','mmddyyyy'), 'IW')+7) - (LEVEL * 7) )+6
 )  
SELECT 
  product, 
  week,
  undist_amt_eod as quantity,
  LAST_VALUE(undist_amt_eod IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY week) repeated_quantity
FROM 
 (
    SELECT 
      product, 
      week_list.week, 
      inv_table.undist_amt_eod
    FROM 
      inv_table PARTITION BY (product)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN week_list ON (week_list.week = inv_table.history_date)
    where 
      inv_table.tab = '*' --Includes all types of this product
  )
ORDER BY product, week;
```

**Week List example output:**

[image]

**Table contents:** Note the table can have multiple tabs per day. The * is the sum of all the tabs for the day, so I'm only interested in the * values.

[image]

I based my code from the oracle example found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm). Unsure why the data output is still not dense.

Comment: is there any data for the 6th and 20th?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your WHERE clause:

```
where inv_table.tab = '*' --Includes all types of this product
```

Because you are doing a right outer join, inv_table.tab will be NULL when there is no match.  Change it to something like one of the following:

```
where inv_table.tab = '*' or inv_table.history_date is null --Includes all types of this product
```

Or, if inv_table.tab can never be NULL, then:

```
where coalesce(inv_table.tab, '*') = '*'
```

Comment: +1 Although personally I would prefer to add `and inv_table.tab = '*'` to the JOIN condition.